# Functional languages that support the passing of stateful things as a parameter

Tags: time, functional-programming, state, programming-languages

I just started learning about functional languages.

I'm currently thinking about how to represent 'stateful', constantly updating things like, say the periodic swaying of a pendulum, or the movement of some environment object in a videogame.

I imagine there are some hacky solutions with recursion and other non-pure looping functions, but I was hoping there was a way to just represent something as a function over time.

i.e. I have some periodic movement I want to represent, so I build some function like `sin x`, and pass in something that represents the constantly updating value of my computers internal clock to that function.

I understand that getting the current time from my computer would be on a per-request basis, and I could just write some imperative code to infinitely loop, call some `get_time()` syscall and then call my functional-lang function with that value, I'm really just hoping this work is already done for me in some standard library of some functional language.

Is there anything analogous to this functionality in any functional programming languages you know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term to search for is "functional reactive programming".

The basic idea is to introduce a notion of "time-varying value" into the language. These are often broken down into *behaviors* and *events*. A *behavior* is a value like "time", which varies continuously. An *event* is discrete, like a mouse click, or when some increasing behavior value passes some threshold. (I think I've heard the term *signal* as a synonym for *behavior*.)

In order for time-varying values to be useful, the results of computing with time-varying values should also be time-varying values. For example, if you extract the second field of the current time, that should a time-varying value that iterates through 0 through 59 over and over.

There has been a lot of work on this idea, but here's a link to one example implementation in JavaScript that you can try out in the browser: http://www.flapjax-lang.org/ (Note the `http` URL. The site has not been updated recently, and the demos tend to fail if you visit the site using `https`.) I recommend starting with the tutorial: http://www.flapjax-lang.org/tutorial/.